# jQuery .click() not working on ajax modalpopupextender button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have to invoke ImageButton (in repeater footer) click event from jQuery on response to ajax modalpopupextender button. I tried the below code but it's not working. It doesn't throw any error but PostBack is not happening.

```
 var isCurrentPortalFormSaveClicked = false;
 var controlsValuesOnload = '';
   var controlsValuesWhileExit = '';


   window.onbeforeunload = beforeUnload;
   window.onload = getValues;

   function getValues() {
   controlsValuesOnload = $('form').serialize();
    }

function beforeUnload() {
if (isCurrentPortalFormSaveClicked == true) return;
controlsValuesWhileExit = $('form').serialize();
if (controlsValuesOnload != controlsValuesWhileExit) {
    return "Your changes have not been saved.  To stay on the page so that                     you can save your changes, click Cancel.";
  }
}

  function confirmExit(callBackMethod, saveButtonId) { 
     controlsValuesWhileExit = $('form').serialize();
   if (controlsValuesOnload != controlsValuesWhileExit) {
return ShowUnSavedChangesWarning(callBackMethod,saveButtonId);
}
 else {
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
return false;
}

  }

  function ShowUnSavedChangesWarning(callBackMethod, saveButtonId) {
  saveButtonControl = saveButtonId;
  callBack = callBackMethod;
  $find('<%= modalPopUpConfirmExitWarning.ClientID %>').show();
  return true;
  }

   function saveFormAndClose() {
     HideUnSavedChangesWarning();
     if (callBack != '' && callBack != null && callBack != undefined) {
         return callBack();

     }
     else if (saveButtonControl != '' && saveButtonControl != undefined) {//if the control is other than ribbon save and close button.
         saveButtonControl.click(); 
         window.open('', '_self', '');
         window.close();
     }
     else if ($('.saveandclose') != null && $('.saveandclose') != '' && $('.saveandclose') != undefined) {

         $('.saveandclose')[0].click();

     }
     return false;
 }

 function closeForm() {
     isCurrentPortalFormSaveClicked = true;
     window.open('', '_self', '');
     window.close();
     return false;
 }


  function SaveNewNotes() {
        //Save Notes
        var notes = $('.newNote').first().val();
        if (notes != null && notes != "") {


            $('.saveNotes')[0].click();
    }
  return true;
 }
```

ASPX:

```
 <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopUpConfirmExitWarning" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
    runat="server" PopupControlID="panelConfirmExitWarning" TargetControlID="btnHiddenConfirmExitWarning"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnHiddenConfirmExitWarning" Style="display: none" />

        <asp:Panel ID="panelConfirmExitWarning" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="ModalWindow">
            <div class="window_header">
                <span id="spanSubscirptionWindowHeader" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="window_body">
                <img src="../Images/Icon_Warning_New.png" />
                <span id="spanConfirmExitExpiryWarning" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="window_footer" align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:DealerWebPortal, DWP_SPAN_Ribbon_Save %>"
                   OnClientClick="return saveFormAndClose();" CssClass="popUp_button" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnDontSave" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:DealerWebPortal, DWP_BTN_Page_Home_DontSave %>"
                    OnClientClick="return closeForm();" CssClass="popUp_button" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:DealerWebPortal, DWP_BTN_Page_DealerEmailSubscription_Cancel %>"
                    CssClass="popUp_button" />
            </div>



        </asp:Panel>
```

Button (to trigger modalpopupextender):

```
<a id="lnkClose" class="close" runat="server"    onclick="isCurrentPortalFormSaveClicked=true;return    confirmExit(SaveNewNotes,null);"> </a>
```

Repeater:

```
     <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrCaseNotes"     OnItemCommand="rptrCaseNotes_ItemCommand">
                                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                                            <table>
                                                                <tr style="width: 650px">
                                                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 50px">
                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="AddNote" Width="16px" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/Images/112_Plus_Blue_32x32_72.jpg"
                                                                            runat="server" CommandName="Add" OnClick="OnAddNotes" OnClientClick="isCurrentPortalFormSaveClicked=true" CssClass="saveNotes" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td style="width: 600px">
                                                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NewNotes" Rows="6" Width="600px" Height="80px" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                                                            MaxLength="2000" CssClass="newNote" />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Are there any JS errors in your browser console? Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: Have you defined this function: HideUnSavedChangesWarning(); ??

Comment: @halfer : No JS errors.

Comment: @vbouk: Yes defined. Below is the function. it triggers the click sever side event when i call "SaveNewNotes" funciton without using modalpopupextender.                                                                          function HideUnSavedChangesWarning() {
      $find('<%= modalPopUpConfirmExitWarning.ClientID %>').hide();
  }

Comment: Catched below messages using Fiddler.  Content-Length mismatch: Request Header indicated 16,421 bytes, but client sent 0 bytes.  


Failed to obtain request body. System.IO.InvalidDataException The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 0, expected 16,421